# How to pull out the employees who have 'first name,lastname and date of birth' as same from Employee table

Tags: t-sql

I need to pull out the records whose First name,lastname and date of birth are of same.
Please find the below example.

```
Employeeid   firstname lastname DOB
00010         ravi      sagi     22/01/1990
00035         ravi      sagi     22/01/1990
00060         vasanth   guptha   20/01/1987
00115         vasanth   guptha   20/01/1987
```

Can you please help in writing the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from
  (
    select *,
           count(*) over(partition by firstname, lastname, DOB) as CC
    from YourTable
  ) as T
where T.CC > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the table to itself comparing the `firstname`, `lastname` and `DOB` to make sure they are the same value and then that the `employeeid` is not the same:

```
select * 
from yourtable t1
inner join yourtable t2
  on t1.firstname = t2.firstname
  and t1.lastname = t2.lastname
  and t1.dob = t2.dob
  and t1.empid != t2.empid
```

the above query could display duplicate records, so you could use the following (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3c5e/4)):

```
select DISTINCT t1.empid,
  t1.firstname,
  t1.lastname,
  t1.DOB
from yourtable t1
inner join yourtable t2
  on t1.firstname = t2.firstname
  and t1.lastname = t2.lastname
  and t1.dob = t2.dob
  and t1.empid != t2.empid
```

Or you can use `EXISTS` (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3c5e/5)):

```
select t1.empid,
  t1.firstname,
  t1.lastname,
  t1.DOB
from yourtable t1
where exists (SELECT *
              FROM yourtable t2
              WHERE t1.firstname = t2.firstname
                and t1.lastname = t2.lastname
                and t1.dob = t2.dob
                and t1.empid != t2.empid)
```

Comment: in case there are more than 2 people with the same name and the same birth, this query will return (rows-1)*rows so 7 same birthdays will return 42 rows

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you are correct, I would probably include a `DISTINCT` on the query to remove any dups...see my edit.

Comment: Distinct is not a good way to resolve a bad query. The join is still processed with the hard strain on the processor, 5 seconds with 2508 identical names/dob. If you want to speed up the query using a join, I surgest using exists (less than 1 second), although Mikaels solution is much better.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I edited to include an `EXISTS` query. I prefer the `over()` version of the solution but I wanted to provide an alternative that could work on outside of sql-server. :)